# Definir un id a un elemento del Spinner

Tags: java, android

Hola tengo un spinner el cual traigo los items desde un xml . Y quisiera saber como identifico cual item elegí. Asignarles un nombre más corto para poder guardarlos más ordenadamente. Ejemplo:

```
<item>Másculino</item>
```

Que en lugar de Másculino lo obtenga como "M".

Guardar de forma corta pero mostrar en la UI de forma normal.

Editado 
Lo que tengo:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterd = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.combo_dignidades,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterg = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.combo_genero,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    genero.setAdapter(adapterg);
    dignidad.setAdapter(adapterd);

    genero.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            dGenero.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    dignidad.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            dDignidad.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Puedes crear otro array con los id, y cuando el usaurio selecciones masculino recuperar esa pocision y con esa posicion ir a buscar en el array de ids

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez Podrías poner un ejemplo en repuestas por favor

Comment: pon lo que has probado, donde le pasar el arreglo al spinner, donde seleciones un elemento

Comment: Ya actualicé el código de spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes los array como `string-array` así:

```
<string-array name="combo_genero">
    <item>Masculino</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="combo_genero_value">
    <item>M</item>
</string-array>
```

Los obtienes en tu actividad de la siguiente manera:

```
Resources res = getResources();
    //String[] generos = res.getStringArray(R.array.combo_genero);
    String[] generosValue = res.getStringArray(R.array.combo_genero_value);
```

Al momento de seleccionar en tu spinner obtienes la posicion del elemento seleccionado:

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),generosValue[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió